# Installed OpenGL wrongly

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to run OpenGL 3 programs but I'm not sure which implementation I'm using and probably set it up wrong.  (I'm a DirectX programmer) While trying to run these demos:

https://github.com/tomdalling/opengl-series/archive/master.zip.

I get this exception:

```
ERROR: WGL: OpenGL profile requested but WGL_ARB_create_context_profile is unavailable
```

This machine is Windows 7 with a 1023MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M (Dell) card.  Has anyone else seen this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know exactly what the issue is.

Most laptops have two graphics cards: A dedicated card (GeForce GT 520M), and an integrated card (Intel HD).

Your integrated card only supports up to OpenGL 3.1, while these demos are requesting OpenGL 3.2.

All you need to to is go into the Nvidia control panel, go into 'Manage 3D Settings', then set the preferred graphics processor to 'High-Performance Nvidia processor'.

After that, the demos should run correctly.

Comment: Thank you!  It was on auto-select, don't know why it would choose the integrated for OpenGL but dedicated for DirectX.